# Java List<T> remove consecutive equal elements

Tags: java, list

I have a `List<Log>`, where Log is a Java Class with various attributes.

I need to delete two consecutive Log objects if they are equal. I defined that two logs are equal if their log_message are equal and their timestamp are very close to each other.

One idea is to go through every log of the list and check if the current is equal to the next. If this is true, then i need to delete the current object from the list and move on.

I need to maintain the order of `List<Log>` (i can sort the list, and then ordenate again by decreasing timestamp if necessary). The `List<Log>` is already ordered by decreasing timestamp.

I tried to do something like this:

```
int i = 0;
ListIterator<T> it = list_tmp.listIterator(); // list_tmp is the List<Log>
while(it.hasNext()){
    current = list_tmp.get(i);
    next = list_tmp.get(i+1);
    if(current.getLogMessage().equals(next.getLogMessage())){
        list_tmp.remove(current);
    }
    i++;
}
```

But i get an error of index out of range.

Am I thinking this wrong? Is there another way to do it better?

Comment: *"Am I thinking this wrong?"* Yes ... your code assumes that if there is a next element (without consuming it for some reason), then there's also another one (the `i+1`), but that's obviously not always the case.

Comment: Hint: what happens when you get to the last item referenced in the Iterator?

Comment: I'd say the real problem is getting duplicate log entries. I feel that's either a bug (racing threads?) or duplicate log entries shouldn't be deleted in the first place (a log is supposed to be as accurate as possible, right?). But I'm not one to judge.

Comment: My advice is, don't modify the original list, instead, build a new list containing only the items you want. It's hard to reason correctly about code which modifies the thing you're working on.

Comment: @smitty1 `Iterator::remove`?

Comment: This general approach is also likely run aground on a `ConcurrentModificationException`.  If you are going to remove elements from a list while an `Iterator` is active over it, then you must do so *via* that iterator (or else stop using the `Iterator`).

Comment: @HTNW, I probably expressed myself poorly. There are no duplicate log entries, it is just that I don't want to show the same log message if the timestamp is too close.

Comment: why not handling this when you are importing the log on the list?
use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html instead of list with Calendars as keys and logs as values, and always compare the new entry with the last

Comment: @Elentriel Thanks for the hint. I'm using Eclipse Link with the method getResultList().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have an iterator - your should use it, and not the indexes:

```
Log prev = null;
Log current = it.next();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    prev = current;
    current = it.next();
    if (current.getLogMessage().equals(next.getLogMessage())) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```